# Selecionar checbox automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um calendário para marcações de refeições. A data e os tipos de refeições estão a ser guardados na mesma coluna da tabela da base de dados.
Quando coloco a quantidade de refeições seleciona automaticamente a checkbox desse tipo de refeições, como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora pretendo que ao colocar o valor no input, que selecione a checkbox desse tipo de refeição e que selecione também automaticamente a checkbox da data de acordo com a data onde coloco a quantidade.
Para isso estou a utilizar este script:

```js
var inputs_ = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number'][name^='arrachar']")]; 
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){ 
  inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){ 
    var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']"); 
    
    box.checked = !getValuesLessorEqualZero([this]);
    
    var firstBox = document.getElementById('firstCB');
    firstBox.checked =true;

    var valueAllLessOrZero = getValuesLessorEqualZero(inputs_);
    if(valueAllLessOrZero) firstBox.checked = false;
  }); 
}

const getValuesLessorEqualZero = (inputs) => {
  var lengthInputs = inputs.length;
  var valueLessOrZero = true;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < lengthInputs && valueLessOrZero; i++) {
    valueLessOrZero = inputs[i].value <= 0 ? true : false;
  }

  return valueLessOrZero;
};
```

mas só funciona bem se for no dia 1 do mês, vou mostrar:
Se for no dia 1 do mês tudo corre bem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se fizer o mesmo para outro dia qualquer do mês, seleciona sempre a checkbox do dia 1, onde tem de selecionar o dia de acordo com o preenchimento, vou mostra:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver este problema?

HTML

```html
$calendar .= "<td bgcolor='$color' data-semana=''><font size='2px'/> 
<input id='firstCB' type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> <strong style='color:#5ca2df'>$year-$month-$day</strong> <br /> 
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div>
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div>
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoC]' value='Almoço_(Dieta)' $marcado_dieta $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço (Dieta)</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd2]' value='$marcado_dieta_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /></div> 
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoD]' value='Lanche' $marcado_lanche $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Lanche</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd3]' value='$marcado_lanche_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /><br /> </div>
</font></center></td>";
```

Comment: Olá sua duvida na verdade e de javascript e html e não php. Poste também o código do html para podermos avaliar melhor.

Comment: @Rodrigo Bezerra Rodrigues já editei a pergunta com o html

Comment: você está marcando pelo id firstCB, que está fixo. Se o seu codigo está sendo montando por um loop no php, voce precisaria tambem ter um ID unico

Comment: @aa_sp, sim o problema está aí, mas como crio esse id  único neste caso?

Comment: utiliza alguma variavel que modifica a cada vez que passa no loop, um contador, uma id do banco,... algo que os distingua. Ou entao você pode fazer algo via js mesmo mas ai tem que trabalhar com seletores.

Comment: @aa_sp, pode colocar um exemplo de um contador para o meu caso?

Comment: @Bruno, voce pode adicionar uma ID qq que vem do banco, ficando _firstCB1, firstCB2, firstCB3,..._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro defina o id no seu html para que não se repita e acrescente o atributo ref nos inputs para depois encontrarmos a data assim:

```html
        $calendar .= "<td bgcolor='$color' data-semana=''><font size='2px'/> 
    <input id='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> <strong style='color:#5ca2df'>$year-$month-$day</strong> <br /> 
    <div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input  ref='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div>
    <div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox'  name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input  ref='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div>
    <div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox'  name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoC]' value='Almoço_(Dieta)' $marcado_dieta $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço (Dieta)</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input  ref='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd2]' value='$marcado_dieta_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /></div> 
    <div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox'  name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoD]' value='Lanche' $marcado_lanche $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Lanche</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input  ref='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd3]' value='$marcado_lanche_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /><br /> </div>
    </font></center></td>";
```

Agora no javascript busque o campo data assim:

```js
var inputs_ = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number'][name^='arrachar']")]; 
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){ 
  inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){ 
    var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']"); 
    
    box.checked = !getValuesLessorEqualZero([this]);
    
    var firstBox = document.querySelector(`#`+this.getAttribute('ref'));
    firstBox.checked =true;

    var valueAllLessOrZero = getValuesLessorEqualZero(inputs_);
    if(valueAllLessOrZero) firstBox.checked = false;
  }); 
}

const getValuesLessorEqualZero = (inputs) => {
  var lengthInputs = inputs.length;
  var valueLessOrZero = true;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < lengthInputs && valueLessOrZero; i++) {
    valueLessOrZero = inputs[i].value <= 0 ? true : false;
  }

  return valueLessOrZero;
};
```

Comment: ao colocar no html `id='firstCB{$year$month$day}'`, quando vou abrir a página dá erro >  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: na solução que apresentou esta parte do código `{$year$month$day}`, mas estou a tentar encontrar a resolução para isso mas não estou a conseguir, pode ajudar?

Comment: Olá desculpe eu corrigi ai olha lá o que era assim {$year$month$day} agora é {$year}{$month}{$day} tente novamente.

Comment: assim já seleciona ao colocar valor, mas devia selecionar se um dos inputs fosse maior que zero, mas mesmo com zero seleciona